# corrupted data in a write-through disk using a live snapshot in virtualbox

Tags: linux, hard-drive, virtualbox, snapshot

I have a linux guest with two disks for / and /home. /home is a write-through disk to keep data safe of snapshot restoring.

The problem is that the *live snapshot* corrupts /home data when restoring it. Probably this is caused by linux cache, because if I add some changes to /home and then I restart the machine, the changes are still there. I have tried to mount /home with the option *sync*, but this didn't solve the problem.

These are the steps to reproduce it:

1. Start a guest linux with a write-through disk mounted as /home
2. When you are logged in to your account, take a *live snapshot*
3. Create a file in /home, e.g. `$ echo 1 > ~/test.txt`
4. Close the machine and restore the new created snapshot.
5. Start again the machine.
6. `$ ls -l ~/`
7. The file test.txt has disappeared...
8. If you remount /home you will find it but corrupted. A `$ ls -l ~/` will show you something like
   `-????????? ? ?    ?      ?            ? test.txt`

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to use filesystem for /home that is freezable and thereby snapshot friendly. XFS has a very reliable freeze/unfreeze mechanism. So if you format your /home partition with xfs, you could use the following procedure.

```
$ xfs-freeze -f /home
<do the snapshotting>
$ xfs-freeze -u /home
```

I haven't tried this with virtualbox but we do something very similar on our production database instances for taking snapshots of our mysql db.

Comment: Sorry by being too late. This helped me. Thank you, kashyap.